# PHP ternary operator not working but does not display any error

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
<?php
    /*if(isset($_COOKIE["telcoProvider"])) {
        $telcoProvider = $_COOKIE["telcoProvider"];

    } else {
        $telcoProvider = "NOT FOUND";
    }*/

    $telcoProvider = isset($_COOKIE["telcoProvider"]) ? $_COOKIE["telcoProvider"] : "NOT FOUND".

    print "<p>Your telecommunication company is <b>$telcoProvider.</b></p>";
?>
```

I have checked the browser and the Cookie is there.

It works with the normal if-else, but not with the ternary operator. It does not proceed to the `print`, yet, it does not display any error either.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a typo, you need to finish your statement with `;`, not with a dot.

Comment: My pinky is short. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$telcoProvider = isset($_COOKIE["telcoProvider"]) ?
 $_COOKIE["telcoProvider"] : "NOT FOUND".
                                        ^
```

What's that dot `(.)` doing there instead of a `;` ?

> I wonder why Eclipse did not say anything?

Try this and you will get to an answer to that question :) Note the dot before `print`

```
$test= 1==1? "Oh nice no print :P " : "Oh" . print("Really?");
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: Eclipse didn't say anything because it's perfectly valid PHP, just not what you wanted